# AND not working with Nested Select sql query

Tags: mysql, nested-select

I have an SQL query that selects a minimum value from a column and requires another value to be equal to 1. I am using a nested select and attempting to use an AND statement. However, after adding the AND, the query results with zero results.

```
SELECT writer_email FROM writerdata_tb WHERE writer_active = 1 AND pending = (SELECT MIN(pending) FROM writerdata_tb) LIMIT 1
```

How should I fix this code to select WHERE that satisfies both?

```
writer_email  |  writer_active | pending
-------------   ---------------  --------
email1@mail            0            1
email2@mail            1            3
email3@mail            1            2
```

The query should result in email3@mail because the record has the least pending and has an active equal to 1.

Comment: I would expect this to work, though it's not the most efficient way. Can you post a sample of table rows together with  a sample of what you would expect the query result to be for those same rows?

Comment: Yes I can, I'll append it to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
SELECT writer_email FROM writerdata_tb WHERE writer_active = 1 AND pending = (SELECT MIN(pending) FROM writerdata_tb WHERE writer_active = 1) LIMIT 1
```

It's due to your second select command it will only select the minimum value regardless the writer_active value

Comment: This works!! So was the difference because I should have selected the minimum were the writer active was equal to one?

Comment: yes, that was absolutely right, there is more detailed explanation to this but i make it much simpler for us to understand each other

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need,

```
SELECT writer_email FROM writerdata_tb WHERE writer_active=1 AND pending = (SELECT MIN(pending) FROM writerdata_tb WHERE writer_active=1) LIMIT 1
```

Your inner select query gives the result `1` for pending and since there is no record where `writer_active=1` and `pending=1`,you get zero rows.